# Gathering Logs within Rack::Test

Tags: ruby, rspec, rack, rack-test

I have a rack application (specifically a Sinatra one, but I don't think that matters) which, when running normally, happily outputs a bunch of information about the requests which are being made of it to STDOUT eg:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jul/2013 10:05:39] "GET /oath2/token?password=ohnoes HTTP/1.1" 404 507 0.0013
```

I'm trying write an extension for `Rack::CommonLogger` that will remove passwords from the logfile, so of course my first task is to write a test.

I have `rack/test` set up with `rspec` like so, but I can't figure out how to capture the outgoing logs so I can scan what's in them! Any ideas?

```
require 'my_webapp'

describe "My Webapp" do
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    @app ||= MyWebapp.new
  end

  it 'should not log the text of any GET password parameter' do
    get '/oauth2/token?password=ohnoes'

    # Not sure about this!

    log_output.should_not =~ /ohnoes/
  end
end
```

Comment: Is it possible for you to share that logger - we need the same solution for rack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stub and set expectations on whatever method your custom logger is calling to write its output.

So, for example, if your custom logger writes directly to `STDERR` with a single argument, you would use:

```
STDERR.stub(:write) {|arg| expect(arg).to_not match(/password/)}
```

If your custom logger writes to the default logger (i.e. `env['rack.errors']`) instead of STDERR, then you would stub the `write` method of that object instead. I would have shown that example, but I can't figure out how to get a hold of the Rack environment within an RSpec test.

A couple of notes on this implementation:

- The use of `any_number_of_times`, as in
  `STDERR.should_receive(:write).any_number_of_times` is deprecated in
  favor of `stub`
- There is no reasonable regex to match strings which
  do *not* contain a particular string, so there's no reasonable way to
  use the form `STDERR.stub(:write).with(/regex/)`

Comment: For me, this answer would be perfect if someone explained "how to get a hold of the Rack environment within an RSpec test."